# Can Julia on Windows 10 Pro run DSP applications?

Tags: windows, julia, signal-processing

I want to use Julia on Windows 10 Pro to do high performance RF multi-antenna DSP because our non-DSP backend software is .NET.  Data is coming from embedded ARM across a USB-2 480-Mbps interface to Windows 10 into .NET and then into files for processing by Julia.

One of our team members said "based on past experience there may be some issues with either Julia or supporting software tools that could make working on Windows a problem".

If Julia can't handle this, then we'll have to have a Linux box with a Windows 10 VM to run the .NET (because there's isn't time to redo the backend on Linux).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking, but this type of question seems perhaps better suited to the Discourse site: https://discourse.julialang.org/  Make sure to mention that you have also posted it to stack overflow, and link to this question.